# Check if Grid/Subgrid exists

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to check if my subgrid exists (is expanded).

I wanna do this because i want to save all my changed data in my grid and all my subgrids with one button. But there isn't always every subgrid expanded (i'll do this in a double-iteration) - so i have to check if the subgrid is there to save it.

I tried

```
if(jQuery("#example").grid) { ... }
```

and

```
if(jQuery("#example")) { ... }
```

But the output of these statements is always "undefined". The grid-names are definitely right - i just wrote here #example for example ;-)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to find if an element exists test length of the jQuery object

```
if(jQuery("#example").length) {
   /* element with ID=example exists*/
}
```

You mention `expanded` but gave no indication with html sample or explanation how `expanded` works.

Also note that ID's can't be duplicated in a page. If you have duplicate ID's would definitely need to see html in order to create better solution for traversing. I mention this due to reference of multiple sub grids and an ID selector being used as sample code

Comment: works perfect for me! Thank you!

I don't use duplicate ID's. My Subgrids are having the number of the row of the mother-grid in their id. "#example_1", "#example_2" ...